# Find a quadratic function that respect these 3 conditions

Tags: calculus, conditional-expectation, regression

I am developing a mobile app and I don't know how to solve this math problem.
p : money
d : time in days
Find a quadratic $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ such that

$f(0)=s$ (where s is for "initial y")

$f(d)=p$

$f′(d)≤4f′(0)$

I did calculus 1 & 2 course and discrete math.
How can I do this ? Thanks

EDITED from accepted answer

Comment: Read this: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: So you want $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ for some numbers $a,b,c$; $f(0)=0$; $f(d)=p$; and $f'(d)\le4f'(0)$. Is that right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Exactly !

Comment: You've accepted an answer here. So what was the point of posting the same question to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369961/find-a-function-that-respect-these-3-conditions (where it will surely be closed and deleted very quickly)? You are abusing these websites.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It's not the same question, maybe you was confused because of the same names

Comment: Sorry – but, still, it's way off-topic for MathOverflow, and it should be possible to take what you've learned at this question and apply it to the other one.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I don't think so because the problem is REALLY different. this one taked less than 20 min to get a response, the new one is now there for many hours on stackexchange and reddit and this is the only answer I got : https://www.reddit.com/r/mathematics/comments/ifbjbw/find_the_function_that_respect_these_3_conditions/g2mscwu?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: So you also posted to reddit without linking! How many other sites have you posted it to? Please, right now, without delay, link the posts on every site to which you have sent it to every other site to which you have sent it! Now!

Comment: @GerryMyerson I sent on reddit and stack exchange and mathoverflow but why are you commenting here ? You are not commenting on the good question. On the new question I linked to the other sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking this:

Find a quadratic $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ such that

1. $f(0) = s$ (where $s$ is my name for "initial y")
2. $f(d) = Q$ (where $Q$ is my name for "y final"
3. $f'(d) \le 4 f'(0)$

i.e., given $d, s$ and $Q$, find the values of $a,b,c$.

Item 1 tells us that
$$c = s; \tag{1}
$$

Item 2 tells us that
$$
ad^2 + bd + c = Q; \tag{2}
$$

Item 3 tells us that
$$
2ad + b \le 4 b. \tag{3}
$$

Simplifying, we have
\begin{align}
c &= s\\
ad^2 + bd + c = Q\\
2ad \le 3b
\end{align}
which reduces to
\begin{align}
ad^2 + bd = Q-s\\
2ad \le 3b
\end{align}
Sadly, this system of equations has infinitely many solutions, so there's no single answer.

Still, let's push on.
\begin{align}
ad = \frac{Q-s}{d} - b\\
ad \le \frac{3}{2} b
\end{align}
so we need for
$$
\frac{Q-s}{d} - b \le \frac32 b$$
or, simplifying slightly, for
$$
\frac{Q-s}{d}  \le \frac52 b
$$
$$
\frac{2(Q-s)}{5d}  \le  b
$$
So ... let's pick
$$
b = \frac{2(Q-s)}{5d}.
$$
So we now know $c$ and $b$, and need only find $a$, which we can do from equation 2;
\begin{align}
ad^2 &= Q - bd - c\\
ad^2 
&= Q - \frac{2(Q-s)}{5d}d - s\\
&= Q - \frac{2(Q-s)}{5} - s\\
&= \frac{5Q - 2(Q-s) - 5s}{5}\\
&= \frac{5Q - 2Q + 2s - 5s}{5}\\
&= \frac{3Q -3s}{5}\\
&= \frac{3}{5}(Q-s)\\
a &= \frac{3}{5d^2}(Q-s).
\end{align}

And that's at least *one* of the possible solutions.

And now re-reading, it looks as if you want $s = 0$, so we get
\begin{align}
a &= \frac{3Q}{5d^2}\\
b &= \frac{2Q}{5d}\\
c &= 0.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, this works for me ! You can write p instead of Q so it can be more clear for other people.